# Is there any script, which is capable to check if there is any unsecured (HTTP) content (scripts, images...) on HTTPS pages?

Tags: javascript, https

Is that even possible? What I want to do is to block these scripts to be loaded and to crash our certificate.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Google "Content Security Policy"

Comment: I'm not sure what you really after but this article by Troy Hunt might be related. Particularly steps 4, 5, and 6. https://www.troyhunt.com/the-6-step-happy-path-to-https/